# como transformar a lista em uma única string

Tags: python

Gostaria que meu código resultasse ao invés de uma lista uma única string Ex: n = 5 o código me retorna
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] eu gostaria que ele me retornasse '12345' transformando todos os elementos em uma única string. oque posso fazer?

```
n = int(input())

previous = []
i = 1

while(i <= n):
    previous.append(i)
    i = i + 1
    if(len(previous) == n):
            print(previous)
```

Comment: Substitua todo o seu código por essa linha `print("".join(map(str,range(1,int(input())+1))))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método `join`, convertendo os itens para `string` antes e concatenando eles a partir de uma string vazia `''`:

```
print(''.join(str(x) for x in previous))
```

Com o input `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` o resultado seria:

```
12345
```

Comment: obrigado funcionou